# python bulk update of tables

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a python dictionary "persons" populated with a query against PostgreSQL. I do some processing which does not need any interaction with the database. So the code goes

```
for person in persons:
    process
```

Based on success/failure of the process, I will set a flag for each record in the dictionary. Once the process is over, I wanted to update a table with the data in the dictionary. Is it possible to do this without looping/iterating? Right now I am doing the update inside the loop. When the list is big, that involves too many database calls.

Comment: You can concatenate SQL `UPDATE`s and run them after the whole query has been formed. That is, in each `process` concatenate something like `UPDATE table SET col=val, ... WHERE condition` to a string which you'll use to run the SQL command.

Comment: That is the option I am exploring. Is there an easier way - like "update table x set y=0 where id in (persons.id)". May be wishful thinking

Comment: You **can** use an `IN` operator in a `WHERE` clause, but I don't think it's possible to set _different_ values for the modified columns. If you want to update the desired columns with the same value for all requested rows, it'll work though.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I plan to do till someone else comes up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, if you can compound queries into a large query string, for example:

```
sql = """ 
   BEGIN;
   UPDATE table SET field = value1 WHERE id = 1;
   UPDATE table SET field = value2 WHERE id = 2;
   ...
   UPDATE table SET field = valueN WHERE id = N;
   END;
"""
```

You will be able to execute one transaction query to generate multiple UPDATE queries.